# ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64, two SDK in swift3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, arm64

Hi I working with two 2 SDK , moca and sentencie,
now the problem is when compile Xcode show me:

> duplicate symbol _kReachabilityChangedNotification in:
>       /Users/dortiz/Documents/IOS/ProcIOS/Pods/MOCA/libMOCALib.a(APPLReachability.o)
>       /Users/dortiz/Documents/IOS/ProcIOS/Frameworks/SENTTransportDetectionSDK.framework/SENTTransportDetectionSDK(Reachability.o)
>   ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The problem is I can't edit Reachability.o or APPLReachability.o
because, are libraries, what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

There are many solution you can try out :-

1. Means that you have loaded same functions twice. As the issue disappear after removing  -ObjC from Other Linker Flags, this means that this option result that functions loads twice.
2. Changing 'No Common Blocks' from Yes to No ( under Targets->Build Settings->Apple LLVM - Code Generation ) fixed the problem.
3. Please check your imported any .m file instead of .h by mistake.

Comment: dont work's, with 'No Common Blocks' and  removing -ObjC

Comment: or You can compile after setting enable testability to NO in your Build settings.

Comment: same result :( , with testability  as no